# PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT not included in Python.h?

Tags: python, c++, import, header-files

I tried to build a C++ library for Python. After running `python setup.py build` for my library, it spat me an error.

```
funcs.cpp:51:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT'
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    ^
funcs.cpp:50:27: error: variable has incomplete type 'struct PyModuleDef'
static struct PyModuleDef cppstats = {
                          ^
funcs.cpp:50:15: note: forward declaration of 'PyModuleDef'
static struct PyModuleDef cppstats = {
              ^
```

I tried to include using the Python.h file from my 2.7 and then 3.8 versions, but they both failed. I found the structure's source file in a disparate folder, but including it is a pain and will probably break if I move anything.

`#include </Users/dominictarro/Downloads/pypy3.6-v7.2.0-osx64/include/Python.h>`

I'm new to C++ so I'm a bit naive as to how compilers work, but I would imagine there's a better way of doing this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I am also new to C extends Python:).

And same problem occured here and I found that may be due to Py2 and Py3's difference(I use py2). *PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT* is defined in python3 so maybe you can use py3 or try to read py2's implementation~

Ref(try to read this if py2): https://docs.python.org/2.7/extending/extending.html#a-simple-example